# How to call an action within the contract with custom permissions?

Tags: action, permissions

Here is my code:

```
void play(account_name player, asset amount) {
   require_auth(player);

   //The part that is throwing the error
   action {
     permission_level{player, N(active)}, //Using the passed in `player` account as ther permission
     N(eosio.token),
     N(transfer),
     currency::transfer {
         .from=player, .to=_self, .quantity=amount, .memo="Deposit"
       }
    }.send();
}
```

When I call the function using:

```
cleos push action mycontract deposit '["myaccount", "30 EOS"]' -p myaccount
```

This is the error I get:

```
3192155ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:406           handle_exception     ] Exception Details: 3090003 unsatisfied_authorization: provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations
transaction declares authority '{"actor":"myaccount","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms, provided permissions [{"actor":"myaccount","permission":"eosio.code"}], and provided keys []
    {"auth":{"actor":"myaccount","permission":"active"},"provided_delay":0,"provided_permissions":[{"actor":"myaccount","permission":"eosio.code"}],"provided_keys":[],"delay_max_limit_ms":3888000000}
    thread-0  authorization_manager.cpp:409 check_authorization
```

Is there a way to perform this action with passed in `account_name`'s as the permission?

How would the behavior need to be changed if I deploy this contract to the mainnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the caller eosio.code permission. Look at this issue:

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4348

Answer (score 0):

Before you push action you can do this:

```
cleos set account permission youraccount active '{"threshold":
 1,"keys": [{"key": "your pub-key","weight": 1}],"accounts":
 [{"permission":{"actor":"you
 account","permission":"**eosio.code**"},"weight":1}]}' owner -p your
 account
```

Comment: Hello @fenchen, normally code should be formatted as code block (indenting four spaces or pressing ctrl+k in the editor). But I think the blockquote formatting is ok in this case, as the highlight is needed.